# What are Wicket PageParameters Recomendations?

Tags: wicket

Lets say im in PageA and want to pass a Person Object with two Strings properties(name and lastname) to PageB. What is the recommended way to proceed?

A) Set 2 PageParameters values, one for each string.
B) Pass the entire person via pageparameter (if posible.)

Sorry guys Im in a project for university and time forces me to ask as fast as I can, so I forgot to write the background.

This is it:

In pageA I have a Person Object, lets say I wat to edit that person in PageB, that is the page for edit persons. I I already have the Object I dont want to query it again just for fun lol. Im using JPA and I would like to edit the object I already READ and then merge it to the DB using Entity Manager.

Answer (score 5):

The question which technique you should use cannot be answered by comparing them to each other. You cannot say on is better than the other. Like rotsch said, it depends on your requirement. For example, if you need to stay stateless and Bookmarkable, you should pass your arguments in a stateless way via POST or GET, maybe using PageParameters. You cannot pass complex Object via PageParameters. If it doesnt matter to you wether being stateless or not as you may already having a session, then I recommend to instantiate your page on your own and pass the object to the constructor or any way you like.

Good practice to accomblish both would be to pass a unique identifier for your object via pageparameters and retrieve your object and its properties based on that Id. This way you got a url parameter which would be intransparant to the user, minimal parameter size, stateless and bookmarkable paging and more reliability for the data you are working with.

But as far as all this doesnt matter to you, just put your object in session ;)

Comment: >The question which technique you should use cannot be answered by >comparing them to each other. 
I Agree.

Comment: +1 for putting the object in the session (edit: preferably in a model)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the use case. With PageParameters the 2 values are sent via GET-Variables in the URL. This way it's easy to change the variables when editing the URL.

Passing the person object makes this safer and allows you to pass the whole object with all the data associated with it.

Comment: If i pass the person i wont have to query it again so i prefer that. But how do object pass via GET encrypted? This doesnt have performance cost?

Comment: Sorry no encrypted i ment serialized.